# Dealing with jsf session and browser refreshes

Tags: session, jsf, myfaces, backing-beans

I'm writing an application in JSF 1.2 that has a session in a backing bean.
The biggest stability issue happens when the user refreshes the page (by pressing F5) or uses the backward arrow in the browser to go back.

I would like some 'smart' (knowledgeable) way to overcome this.

The most common exception I get is that after a refresh, the user will try to continue using the application and would get a:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException - duplicate Id for a component
```

in the browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bind physically different components by `binding` to one and same bean property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `smart (knowledgeable)` way to overcome this, add [seam](http://seamframework.org) to your jsf application. They have solved the backbutton problems in JSF